Change color of dot border inside plot
I have a table looking like this:
UMAP1   UMAP2   Tissue  Color   Shape   Size    Alpha
SRR10264719 -29.4889521358772   -8.66297910678254   Skeletal muscle #DB6443 15  2   0.3
SRR10264720 -28.1647041271537   -9.2389962165056    Skeletal muscle #DB6443 15  2   0.3
SRR10264721 -27.7779018467139   -7.77324674358062   Skeletal muscle #DB6443 15  2   0.3
SRR10264722 -28.9240216504801   -6.88035148983915   Skeletal muscle #DB6443 15  2   0.3
SRR10264489 -22.4755554470652   -9.4372904287924    Heart   plum    15  2   0.3
SRR10264490 -24.5858630522468   -9.37159135316227   Heart   plum    15  2   0.3
SRR10264491 -23.5112974481147   -8.18832270248269   Heart   plum    15  2   0.3
SRR10264492 -23.7073667407391   -10.6988347889211   Heart   plum    15  2   0.3
SRR8858261  11.2999233639759    25.452477257942 Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858262  8.40396056507533    25.086067501417 Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858263  9.23640858352789    27.7242020484115    Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858264  13.4228943596782    25.7918988101462    Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858265  9.7026729110401 26.1751441698723    Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858266  12.7975441335269    27.5443456721261    Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858267  9.75248892382621    29.237780219553 Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR8858268  11.6426304090961    29.2826481026824    Skin    #F0C57F 15  2   0.3
SRR10264369 9.57409618588361    -17.4440954361671   Liver   goldenrod3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264370 7.13380411765329    -18.9314881153715   Liver   goldenrod3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264371 7.3662972780314 -16.8191054906869   Liver   goldenrod3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264372 9.04831605411037    -19.1809371287194   Liver   goldenrod3  15  2   0.3
DRR041463   2.84768093587914    17.6861742287487    Lung    goldenrod4  15  2   0.3
DRR041468   2.8537227567788 16.0233446192056    Lung    goldenrod4  15  2   0.3
DRR041613   0.630704982187184   16.9203264395938    Lung    goldenrod4  15  2   0.3
DRR041352   4.05721706817545    18.0474441813888    Lung    goldenrod4  15  2   0.3
SRR10264389 18.8927490332881    9.28576287581545    Brain   lavender    15  2   0.3
SRR10264390 17.8106982666337    8.54535104625841    Brain   lavender    15  2   0.3
SRR10264391 19.5391629168044    7.54601874346748    Brain   lavender    15  2   0.3
SRR10264392 17.6698571811266    6.94029901957597    Brain   lavender    15  2   0.3
SRR10264628 10.7937508473859    1.37149747657834    Ovary   lavenderblush3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264629 8.89446745023961    0.0932344287227481  Ovary   lavenderblush3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264630 10.6293080051024    -0.00364933963943179    Ovary   lavenderblush3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264631 9.54317421276131    1.97508473258641    Ovary   lavenderblush3  15  2   0.3
SRR10264237 -20.0479454341046   8.2666936938468 Placenta    rosybrown2  15  2   0.3
SRR10264238 -20.5343084871942   6.38692596028833    Placenta    rosybrown2  15  2   0.3
SRR10264239 -22.3246254335286   6.75631362574979    Placenta    rosybrown2  15  2   0.3
SRR10264240 -21.8540761194109   8.33765688003512    Placenta    rosybrown2  15  2   0.3
DRR041531   -6.87143083117679   19.0947543495592    Cartilage   lightskyblue3   15  2   0.3
DRR041538   -8.05818223873333   20.3413725544573    Cartilage   lightskyblue3   15  2   0.3
DRR041557   -6.56144197282658   21.1773753093274    Cartilage   lightskyblue3   15  2   0.3
DRR041563   -9.31079238910149   19.900869277886 Cartilage   lightskyblue3   15  2   0.3
DRR041586   -7.5905836174761    22.1629492312742    Cartilage   lightskyblue3   15  2   0.3
SRR10264269 -8.44036450914174   -0.378680282725901  Pancreas    ivory4  15  2   0.3
SRR10264270 -10.8583384308232   -0.936011209193957  Pancreas    ivory4  15  2   0.3
SRR10264271 -9.70550008466581   0.583328913749887   Pancreas    ivory4  15  2   0.3
SRR10264272 -8.92506135202094   -1.90185557735393   Pancreas    ivory4  15  2   0.3
SRR1044425  24.7067790317161    -16.8828111492488   Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR1044427  23.9977470876999    -19.306839445552    Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR1044429  22.9037711753863    -17.3093261528297   Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR1044431  26.4948062612985    -17.884578333976    Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR1044433  26.0825733060916    -15.9223841335034   Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR1044434  25.270562104109 -18.2743320908728   Plasma  lemonchiffon2   15  2   0.3
SRR10264980 -1.56087417166404   -2.92206139721637   Stomach palegreen1  15  2   0.3
SRR10264981 0.704975448076853   -0.379695100056864  Stomach palegreen1  15  2   0.3
SRR10264982 0.0942849428300065  -2.93075673406752   Stomach palegreen1  15  2   0.3
SRR10264983 -2.18261250377022   -1.10783397565846   Stomach palegreen1  15  2   0.3
SRR10263632 8.36030790306862    -10.184714869195    Jejunum palegreen3  15  2   0.3
SRR10263633 6.06834223441164    -8.58658779050061   Jejunum palegreen3  15  2   0.3
SRR10263634 6.57889119925982    -10.886954188198    Jejunum palegreen3  15  2   0.3
SRR10263635 8.23384654890928    -8.64515294061689   Jejunum palegreen3  15  2   0.3
SRR10263548 1.17307007271145    -9.19407674808854   Ileum   olivedrab2  15  2   0.3
SRR10263549 0.747326205735879   -12.588912052594    Ileum   olivedrab2  15  2   0.3
SRR10263550 2.79101267585893    -10.530970980178    Ileum   olivedrab2  15  2   0.3
SRR10263551 0.59141221685381    -10.8345094649726   Ileum   olivedrab2  15  2   0.3
SRR10263656 -3.30788354653985   -8.89097981141917   Duodenum    olivedrab4  15  2   0.3
SRR10263657 -3.00748076660189   -11.6326365724623   Duodenum    olivedrab4  15  2   0.3
SRR10263658 -1.60361484652028   -7.96247236759856   Duodenum    olivedrab4  15  2   0.3
SRR10263659 -1.77561633959224   -10.3343928488708   Duodenum    olivedrab4  15  2   0.3
SRR10264129 -11.529737474425    -18.387474886281    Thyroid gland   darkolivegreen3 15  2   0.3
SRR10264130 -9.43975139106429   -17.7061080433972   Thyroid gland   darkolivegreen3 15  2   0.3
SRR10264131 -13.2754357748172   -19.1171448762017   Thyroid gland   darkolivegreen3 15  2   0.3
SRR10264132 -10.9419187922156   -19.4861990067855   Thyroid gland   darkolivegreen3 15  2   0.3
Elephant_Blood  19.669139110699 -18.8660104394324   Plasma  lemonchiffon2   28  2.5 0.3
Sample1_muscle  -29.0572558711648   -12.2725979676656   Skeletal muscle #DB6443 2   4   1

And the following code to generate a plot:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstar)
library(ggh4x)

color_final_small = c(rep("#DB6443", 4), rep("plum", 4), rep("#F0C57F",8), rep("goldenrod3",4), rep("goldenrod4",4), rep("lavender",4), 
                      rep("lavenderblush3",4), rep("rosybrown2",4),  rep("lightskyblue3",5), rep("ivory4",4), rep("lemonchiffon2",6),
                      rep("palegreen1",4), rep("palegreen3",4), rep("olivedrab2",4), rep("olivedrab4",4), rep("darkolivegreen3",4), rep("black", 2))



legend_border = c("#DB6443", "plum", "#F0C57F", "goldenrod3", "goldenrod4", "lavender", 
                  "lavenderblush3", "rosybrown2", "lightskyblue3", "ivory4", "lemonchiffon2",
                  "palegreen1","palegreen3","olivedrab2","olivedrab4","darkolivegreen3")
legend_border = factor(legend_border, levels=c("#DB6443", "plum", "#F0C57F", "goldenrod3", "goldenrod4", "lavender", 
                                               "lavenderblush3", "rosybrown2", "lightskyblue3", "ivory4", "lemonchiffon2",
                                               "palegreen1","palegreen3","olivedrab2","olivedrab4","darkolivegreen3"))


axis <- ggh4x::guide_axis_truncated(
  trunc_lower = unit(0, "npc"),
  trunc_upper = unit(1, "cm"))


tiff("Fig_3D.tiff", height = 70, width = 85, units = 'mm', res=600)
ggplot(UMAP_table_small, aes(x=UMAP1, y=-UMAP2, fill=Color, starshape=Shape)) + 
  geom_star(size=UMAP_table_small$Size, color= color_final_small, alpha=UMAP_table_small$Alpha) + 
  
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Skeletal muscle", "Heart", "Skin", "Liver", "Lung", "Brain", "Ovary",
                               "Placenta", "Cartilage", "Pancreas", "Plasma", "Stomach", "Jejunum", "Ileum",
                               "Duodenum", "Thyroid gland"),
                    values = c("#DB6443", "plum", "#F0C57F", "goldenrod3", "goldenrod4", "lavender", 
                               "lavenderblush3", "rosybrown2", "lightskyblue3", "ivory4", "lemonchiffon2",
                               "palegreen1","palegreen3","olivedrab2","olivedrab4","darkolivegreen3")) +
  scale_starshape_manual(labels = c("Human", "Test1", "Test2"),
                         values = c(15, 28, 2),
                         guide = guide_legend(override.aes =list(fill = "black", size=2.5))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order=2, override.aes =list(starshape=15, colour=legend_border, alpha=0.5, size=2.5), nrow=16)) +
  
  theme_minimal() +
  
  ylim(c(-30,20)) + xlim(c(-30,30)) +
  xlab("UMAP1") + ylab("UMAP2") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  guides(x = axis, y = axis) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(linewidth=0.3, arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(5, 'pt')))) +
  
  theme(axis.title.x =element_text(size=6, margin = margin(t = 5), hjust=0, family="Helvetica"),
        axis.title.y =element_text(size=6, margin = margin(r = 2.5), hjust=0, family="Helvetica"),
        plot.margin = margin(t=0.25, b=0.25, l=0.25, r=0.25, "cm")) +
  
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.65, 'lines')) + 
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(1.5,"lines"),
        legend.margin = margin(-13,0,0,0)) +
  
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=6, family="Helvetica"),
        legend.justification ="top") +

ggtitle("microRNAs") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 7, family="Helvetica")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))
  
dev.off()

which generates the following plot:

My issue is that I would like to apply the Alpha values to the fill of the dots, while at the same time, I would like to set the alpha of the borders of the dots in the plot and in the legend to 1. As it is now, the borders get an alpha approximately a bit less than what I set up for the fill, both in the plot and in the legend.
I have tried playing around with override.aes and color or fill values but I cannot manage to make it work.
Does anyone have a clue of how to do it?

OK so the obvious solution, using scales::alpha on the fill scale colours doesn't work, which I suspect is a problem with ggstar.

Yeah I already tried that reading other threads, but as you say it did not work... I somehow made it work but I end up losing the color legend completely by adding two geom_star layers, one for fill and one for color.

I wonder if it could work to specify some alpha in the color_final_small, e.g. replace rep("#DB6443", 4) with rep("#DB644344", 4), where the hex code ends with two more alphanumeric digits specifying alpha. As a hack, you might also add a layer that is fully transparent, but with overriding alpha in the legend, so that the legend dots get solid borders.

As already suggested in the comments using scales::alpha is the canonical approach to achieve your desired result. However, to make this work we have to set alpha = NA in geom_star. Also note that I switched to mapping on aesthetics and scales instead of passing vectors of colors, ... to geom parameters.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstar)
library(ggh4x)

axis <- ggh4x::guide_axis_truncated(
  trunc_lower = unit(0, "npc"),
  trunc_upper = unit(1, "cm")
)

UMAP_table_small$shape <- dplyr::case_match(
  UMAP_table_small$SampleID,
  "Elephant_Blood" ~ "Test1",
  "Sample1_muscle" ~ "Test2",
  .default = "Human"
)

ggplot(UMAP_table_small, aes(
  x = UMAP1, y = -UMAP2,
  fill = Tissue, starshape = shape, size = shape
)) +
  geom_star(
    aes(alpha = shape)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = setNames(
      scales::alpha(
        c(
          "#DB6443", "plum", "#F0C57F", "goldenrod3", "goldenrod4", "lavender",
          "lavenderblush3", "rosybrown2", "lightskyblue3", "ivory4", "lemonchiffon2",
          "palegreen1", "palegreen3", "olivedrab2", "olivedrab4", "darkolivegreen3"
        ), .3
      ),
      c(
        "Skeletal muscle", "Heart", "Skin", "Liver", "Lung", "Brain", "Ovary",
        "Placenta", "Cartilage", "Pancreas", "Plasma", "Stomach", "Jejunum", "Ileum",
        "Duodenum", "Thyroid gland"
      )
    )
  ) +
  scale_starshape_manual(
    values = setNames(
      c(15, 28, 2),
      c("Human", "Test1", "Test2")
    ),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black", size = 2.5))
  ) +
  scale_size_manual(
    values = setNames(
      c(2, 2.5, 4),
      c("Human", "Test1", "Test2")
    )
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = setNames(
      c(NA, NA, 1),
      c("Human", "Test1", "Test2")
    )
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 2, override.aes = list(starshape = 15))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL, limits = c(-30, 30), guide = axis) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL, limits = c(-30, 20), guide = axis) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_line(
      linewidth = 0.3,
      arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(5, "pt"))
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      size = 6, margin = margin(t = 5), hjust = 0,
      family = "Helvetica"
    ),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      size = 6, margin = margin(r = 2.5), hjust = 0,
      family = "Helvetica"
    ),
    plot.margin = margin(t = 0.25, b = 0.25, l = 0.25, r = 0.25, "cm"),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.65, "lines"),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(1.5, "lines"),
    legend.margin = margin(-13, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 6, family = "Helvetica"),
    legend.justification = "top",
    plot.title = element_text(family = "Helvetica", face = "bold")
  ) +
  labs(x = "UMAP1", y = "UMAP2", title = "microRNAs")


